# Highcharts slow performance when adding more than 10 series

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, highcharts

I am adding the series using the code below. Now we are talking of 10~20 series, the UI freezes while doing so and it becomes increasingly slow. And this happens in a PC browser. My hope is to use these charts in a Android WebVIEW on a tablet (kitkat).

Any suggestions how to increase performance?

```
            for (var x in currentSerie) {
                chart.addSeries({
                    name: currentSerie[x].Name,
                    data: currentSerie[x].Data,
                    lineWidth: currentSerie[x].lineWidth || 1,
                    color: currentSerie[x].color || '',
                    dataGrouping: {
                        approximation: "average",
                        enabled: false,
                        forced: true,
                        units: [['hour', [1]]]
                    },
                    marker: {
                        enabled: true,
                        radius: 1
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        valueDecimals: 1,
                        valueSuffix: currentSerie[x].Unit || ''
                    },
                    shadow: false,
                }, false);

            }

            chart.redraw();
```

Comment: Have you tried to get rid of webview and compare results? how huge is your data? Have you any example serie?

Comment: Data at the moment is about 10-120 Series and 50 points per Serie. Same results in chrome browser directly. Within android how would i remove the webview?

Comment: Could you replicate your example as live demo?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and found the following to be the culprit.

```
marker: {
    enabled: true,
    radius: 1
},
```

If you remove forcing the markers to be enabled and let the chart determine when to display the markers, the performance is much better.

Answer (score 0):

As it looks like you are using Highstock (because of the `dataGrouping`), this is a clear point of performance gain. You've set it to be `enabled: false`. Setting it to `true` for large amounts of data can help immensely. From [the datagrouping documentation](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/data-grouping):

> Data grouping replaces a sequence of data points in a series with one grouped point...
>
> Grouping is activated [if] there are many data points in the chart. As well as increasing performance it makes it easier to spot trends in a chart.

Some other general performance gains for Highcharts charts can be found from [the FAQ](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions#optimize-performance):

> When working with series with a high number of data points, there are a few things to consider.
>
> 1. For line plots, it is recommended that you disable point markers, as these will add a performace overhead. See http://highcharts.com/demo/line-time-series.
> 2. Disabling shadows increases performance, as three shadow elements are created for each shape that includes a shadow.
> 3. For large column series, it is recommended that you disable the initial animation, [plotOptions.column.animation](http://api.highcharts.com/#plotOptions.column.animation), at least for VML based browsers. The best way to distinguish between fast SVG browsers and slower VML browsers is to use the Highcharts.svg boolean property.

Comment: All this is helpful, but I believe the real issue comes from having so many Series and not because of the number of points per Serie. I was not able to find anything regarding # of Series in highcharts documentation.